# How can I update weights of the previous learned model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, transfer-learning

I am trying to develop a neural network model to predict player action in a football computer game. Because we do not have much data at the beginning, I utilize from another existing dataset. In order to develop this model I use a transfer learning approach to learn weights from real world football match data. So, I use the weights from the previously trained model on football game data to initialize the weights of my model for prediction in a computer game.

However, when system runs for a while, the data will be accumulated so that I can use it to enhance prediction. My question is how can I use accumulated computer game data in some time intervals to make initial weights more accurate? I will appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm confused, because I think you answered this for yourself: a simple way is to train on your new data, initializing the network based on transfer learning.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy You seem to be correct but the problem here is it will take huge time to get enough training data. After some amount of data, I want to adjust the model weights accordingly but I don't know if there is such a method.

Comment: Why not [incrementally learn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_learning) as more data become available?

Comment: Yes I will use incremental learning. Thanks a lot!